# Each do according to convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know ruby/ rails is all about convention so I thought I'd ask what the appropriate way to do something like this is:

```
  <% @event.prices.each do |price| %>
      <% price_value = price.price > 0 ? "FREE" : price.price %> <!-- ** this line ** -->
      <% if price.name.length > 0 %>
          <div>$<%= price_value %> - <%= price.name %></div>
      <% else %>
          <div>$<%= price_value %> - Ticket Type <%= price.id + 1 %></div>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

As you can see, I'm setting price_value to avoid a huge set of if statements, but my gut is telling me that there is a more appropriate way to do this in ruby. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what `prices` is... It looks like a relation.  If it is, then you have a `Price` object, which you could put a method on, call it `value` or something like that, which does your logic for you:

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base

  def value
    self.price > 0 ? "FREE" : self.price
  end

end
```

Then in your view, you would just be able to call `price.value`:

```
<% @event.prices.each do |price| %>
  <% if price.name.length > 0 %>
    <div>$<%= price.value %> - <%= price.name %></div>
  <% else %>
    <div>$<%= price.value %> - Ticket Type <%= price.id + 1 %></div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You could follow the same convention with `name` as well...  Something like:

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base

  def value
    self.price > 0 ? "FREE" : self.price
  end

  def get_name
    self.name.present? ? self.name : "Ticket Type #{self.id + 1}"
  end

end
```

Then your view would look like:

```
<% @event.prices.each do |price| %>
  <div>$<%= price.value %> - <%= price.get_name %></div>
<% end %>
```

Since I'm on a roll (and obviously had *way* too much caffeine today), then you could create a helper method which would give you `$<%= price.value %> - <%= price.get_name %>`

```
module PriceHelper

  def generate_price_value_and_name(price)
    "$#{price.value} - #{price.get_name}"
  end

end
```

Now your view would be:

```
<% @event.prices.each do |price| %>
  <div><%= generate_price_value_and_name(price) %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is viable but as the "value" is purely presentational, it would also make sense for this to be in a helper, or better yet, a view model / decorator (using [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) for example).

Comment: Totally...  Thus why my caffeine-infused fingers just added the helper logic. :)

Comment: Haha that's very thorough. Thank you! Also, @numbers1311407 +1 for the draper reference

Comment: Thanks - I try my best...  But I need to lay off the coffee.

Comment: @Rob NP.  I think it's a far better pattern than helpers.  I was about to advise to use draper with caution, but it seems like it's come a long way in the past few years.  In any case, here are [some alternatives](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_presenters) if draper isn't what you want.